# div container does not move into gap using css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a team page. But my team details div container simply does not move into the gap available. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XxDFb/5/

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="team-wrapper">
<div class="team-member-photo">
    <img alt="pic" src="http://placehold.it/134x108">
</div>
    <div class="team-member-social-network-links"> 
        <a class="url" href="http://www.repeatpenguin.com" title="repeatpenguin.com" rel="me">Twitter</a> / <a class="url" href="http://www.repeatpenguin.com" title="repeatpenguin.com" rel="me">Facebook</a>
    </div>
    <div class="team-details">
        <p class="name">Firstname Surname</p>
        <p class="job-title">Job title</p>
        <p class="email">Email Address</p>
        <p class="tel">112-123-1232</p>
        <p class="desc">CONTENT BLOCK</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.team-wrapper {
    background-color:#dedede;
    padding:10px;
}

div.team-member-photo{
    width:135px;
    height:109px;
}

div.team-member-social-network-links{
    width:135px;
    height:109px;    
}

div.team-details {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:300px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to css

```
div.team-details {
    top: 20px;
    left: 450px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

or to get  good effect you can make use js

```
$('div.team-details').css('left',parseInt($('.team-wrapper').width() - 340)+'px');
```

Answer (score 2):

- add `overflow:hidden;` in your `div.team-wrapper`
- add another div `div.newDiv` which will contain `div.team-member-photo` and `div.team-member-social-network-links`
- property of `.newDiv` will be ::

  ```
  .newDiv{
   overflow:hidden;
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
   float:left;
  }
  ```

YOUR UPDATED FIDDLE :: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XxDFb/15/)**